# Mobile Device Security

Tags: mobile, phone

Are there any other security threats to a mobile device other then a rogue app?

I am trying to secure a set of business phones and tablets and while anti-virus applications are possible, I don't see viruses of any kind really a threat. Seems most likely someone would download a rogue app that would act as a trojan.

Comment: This is overly broad...  But yes,  modern smart phones use a complex OS and there are a lot of threats.

Comment: Too broad and possible duplicate of [Top Mobile Device Security Concerns?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10782/top-mobile-device-security-concerns). Besides that, you might want to read the answers to questions like [Mobile phone security eavesdropping based on data transfer](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/6751/26145) and [Android security without updates](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/8548/26145). Generally, your mobile device is a mobile computer with a full-fledged OS. Therefore, almost all OS security problems also exist on mobile devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several concerns. You will need to make sure the phones are encrypted and password secured so that no-one can access confidential data. In case of theft you need to be able to wipe all confidential data remotely. Furthermore you need to make sure that  your phones do not get rooted/jailbroken (as this even pose more threats). You will also need to keep them up to date.

A smartphone these days is like a smaller version of your notebook. It can practically do the same and is thus exposed to at least the same attack vectors as a regular computer.